# Excel report sent automatically through outlook. However Outlook constantly goes not responding which then seizes up excel, hanging the report

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I run several Excel files that generate reports and send them through outlook to various recipients.  However, Outlook has become a constant point of failure by constantly going non-responding, which causes excel to lock up and then the report wont run.  What's worse, is that future excel reports also wont run because even if I error handle the blocked excel, future runs of the file will yield no better results as the mechanism for sending the data is still non-responsive.

Is there any way that the excel vba can recognize/resolve a frozen instance of outlook?  Can a .bat script file which calls the excel file to run include a force close of Outlook?  Is there a better method for sending these reports (which are in HTML format with charts and attachments) that bypasses outlook altogether?

The vba for sending the email is the Ron de Bruin script that's pretty common online, I have made little to no modification of it across my workbooks.  I haven't been able to find a solution that seems to match my problem yet.  So far I cannot identify the point of failure in Outlook (through the day on my regular machine it has a habit of just failing and needing to be force closed, without any excel scripts running)

Edit: Adding the code used for one of the workbooks.  There is no rhyme or reason to what causes outlook to go non-responsive and sometimes it does so between runs.

Here is the code:

```
'****** Outlook Mailing Section ********
Dim Rge5 As Range
Set Rge5 = Ws3.Range(Mail1Str)


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

strBody = "Snapshot of Canada Tie Ups Over 10 Hours." & "<br> " & _
"Data pulled from CMA and includes completed trips for today and yesterday at time of data pull.  " & "<br> " & _
"Excludes Yards, TCS under 12 Hours, and Work Trains under 16 hours." & "<br> " & _
"Switch time also includes Relieved Responsibility where applicable."
    
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    '.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = Add1Str
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = "myemailaddress"
    .Subject = "Tie Ups Over 10 Hours"
    .HTMLBody = strBody & "<br> " & RangetoHTML(Rge5) & "<br> "
    .send
    '.display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Please share your code (as text) and a link to Ron de Bruin's code.

Comment: What code exactly do you use? What line of code exactly causes Outlook to be unresponsive?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Added code to original question.  I cannot link the issue to any one workbook or code.  Outlook for myself and others here has been inherently unstable.  Sometimes when I check the machine it runs on, outlook itself is just not responding, even without an excel file funning.